# magento 2 How to overwrite the existing style.css

Tags: theme, css, magento2

I need to customize css in magento 2.

For example My theme name is "inchoo" at following path :-
  - `C:\wamp\www\magento2\app\design\frontend\Magento\inchoo`

Currently I am facing following issues to apply customize css in different scenarios :-

1. How to overwrite the `style.css` in custom theme (inchoo)
2. how to add custom css (`theme.css`) for specific page ie: in catalog product view page?
3. how to add custom(`home.css`) css which will include in all over the site?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to try just now to confirm, but here is my understanding

For 1. You replace files by using the same file path as the original style and making sure your module loads later.

2 & 3. You use a layout file to add a CSS reference. It is a matter of finding the right file to add it to. Eg to a global page layout file like 2-column etc, or a specific page. I think fairly recently a  element was added instead of using a block to register CSS assets.

If you don't get it going, I will create an internal team request for a demo. We have built up a list of little demos that people are starting on. These seem like good little contributions. (They would eventually get into the manuals.)

Answer (score 0):

For 2.)
Inside your layout file use the following:

```
<head>
      <css src="/path/to/file.css" />
</head>
```